# What is the purpose of a resistor in an OR gate?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

What is the purpose of a resistor in an OR gate? Isn't it useless since the gate works even if the resistor is absent?

[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic , too simple for Electrical Engineering : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17915/.

Comment: Are you certain it would work without the resistor? Without the resistor, what pulls the output down to logic low level when both inputs are low?

Comment: Relevant Q & A at EESE: [Diode Logic Gates](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131860/diode-logic-gates)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with a shout-out to Alfred Centauri for correcting me:

My mistake was considering no potential and $0$ V as same.

If resistor branch is absent then circuit would be incomplete when both input voltages are $0$. Thus there would be no output voltage. The presence of resistor and ground branch assigns $0$ V to the output voltage.

Comment: I believe it's called a pulldown resistor.

Comment: @nielsnielsen it is indeed. If both inputs are 0, the diodes will not be forward biased and will not conduct. The output will be floating without the pull-down resistor.